# Quebra de linha alterando css

Tags: javascript, css, layout-responsivo

Estou trabalhando com grids e preciso saber se há alguma forma de capturar o número de linha da box (Geralmente 1) para diminuir o número da fonte para que caiba na box de forma a ocupar somente uma linha.

**Obs: Já testei autofill em js, mas no caso a altura da div não é fixa, por isso não funciona.**

Exemplo e explicação adicional [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/b6gmjj52/1/).

Comment: Uma forma seria usar javascript e contar o número de caracteres `strong.length`, e testar com quantos caracteres a frase começa a quebrar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer seria contando o número de caracteres e alterar o CSS com jQuery conforme o tamanho.

Exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#box p').each(function(index, el){
        $texto = $(this).text().trim();
        $len = $texto.length;
        if($len > 29 && $len <= 56){
         $(el).css('font-size','17px');   
        } else if($len > 56){
         $(el).css('font-size','8px');   
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
#box{width:400px;border:1px solid #999;padding:5px;margin:0 auto;}
#box p{font-size:34px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <p> Vestibulum id aliquet ligula.  </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ornare risus sit amet metus vestibulum volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Realmente funciona, mas uma solução mais responsiva ainda seria bem-vinda, já que trabalhando com % a quebra de linha pode acontecer ainda em resoluções pequenas. :)